# Is $F(x, y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{y^n}$ elementary?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, functions

Let’s define a function $F: \{c \in \mathbb{C}| |c| < 1\} \times (1; \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by the following expression: $F(x, y)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{y^n}$. It it is rather obvious that this series converges on $\{c \in \mathbb{C}| |c| < 1\} \times (1; \infty)$, and thus $F(x, y)$ is well defined. My question is: is $F$ elementary?

The definition of elementary functions I use:

> Suppose $D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$. Then the set of elementary functions on $D$ is defined as the minimal set of functions $El(D) \subset {f: D \to \mathbb{C}}$, that satisfies the following conditions:
>
> 1) $\forall i \leq n \text{ } id_n:(z_1, ... , z_n) \mapsto z_i \text{ } \in El(D)$
>
> 2) $\forall c \in \mathbb{C} \text{ } const_c:(z_1, ... , z_n) \mapsto c \text{ } \in El(D)$
>
> 3) $\forall f, g \in El(D) \text{ } f + g: (z_1, ... , z_n) \mapsto f(z_1, ... , z_n) + g(z_1, ... , z_n) \text{ } \in El(D)$
>
> 4) $\forall f, g \in El(D) \text{ } fg: (z_1, ... , z_n) \mapsto f(z_1, ... , z_n)g(z_1, ... , z_n) \text{ } \in El(D)$
>
> 5) $\forall f \in El(D) \text{ } exp(f): (z_1, ... , z_n) \mapsto e^{f(z_1, ... , z_n)} \text{ } \in El(D)$
>
> 6) $\forall f \in El(D) \text{ such that } (-\infty; 0] \cap f(D) = \emptyset \text{ } ln(f): (z_1, ... , z_n) \mapsto ln(f(z_1, ... , z_n)) \text{ } \in El(D)$